# Bath Fan/Light Wiring

Tags: switch, light, fans

12/2 Line coming to box where SW will be installed. I want one SW for vanity and fan lights, the other for just the fan. SW is a Legrand RCD11 paddle switch with two SP SW going to a 14/3 to the fan/light.

Fan has black wire to black, white to white, ground to ground connected to 14/3. Light black wire is connected to 14/3 red wire.

I have the black 12/2 line going to COM A. Load A has red wire from fan light and jumper back to white. Load B has black wire to fan. white lines are tied together.

I vanity light and fan working separately but fan will shut off when light is turned on. The light on the fan is inop.

Help!!!

Comment: Why the 12/2 coming in but the 14/3 coming out?

Comment: Coz OP heard you use 14/3 for light-fan legs?   OP you need to use 12/3 since it's a 20A circuit.  Also if it's in a bathroom, let us know if this circuit powers a bathroom recep, and if it does, what else in the house does it power?